# How to remove all data from table using FMDB

Tags: iphone, ios, fmdb

I want to delete all data from table in my database. I am using FMDB.And i have used this code but it will not delete data from my table.

```
-(BOOL) deleteAll
{

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
    [db open];

    BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"TRUNCATE TABLE customers"];

    [db close];

    return success;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @DharaParekh it does not display any error just data does not deleted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this code.

```
BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM customers"];
```

As long as i know Sqlite does not support `TRUNCATE` query.

Answer (score 2):

Although `DELETE` command will work it is slow because it selects each row and than proceeds to delete it.

If you are deleting the whole table it is better to `DROP` the table and than recreate it:

```
BOOL result =  [db executeUpdate:@"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;"];
BOOL resultTwo = [db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(name text primary key, age int)"]; //or course fields in your table will be different
```

Swift (for completeness sakes):

```
let dropTable = "DROP TABLE customers"
let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(dropTable, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
if !result {
     print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
} 
let createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(name text primary key, age int)"
if !contactDB.executeStatements(createTable) {
     print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
}
```

reference: [truncate SQLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_truncate_table.htm)